# Is there a tool to help reduce #include statements

Tags: c++, qt, code-analysis

We've got this huge project (it's C++ with Qt) with several hundred files with many unneeded includes. The compile time suffers accordingly, so we would want to remove unneeded #include-statements, where possible, for example by using forward declarations.
Despite the vast amount of code-analysis-tools out there, I couldn't find one that helps reduce #include-statements (or at least they don't seem to advertise it that much). Would you know of any tool that helps reducing #include-statments?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: not sure if it's really a duplicate as IDEs differ and I'm specifically looking for large-scale solutions (for several hundred files). But thanks for pointing it out anyway, maybe I'll find something there.

Comment: well, I'd say remove all the includes and then let the tools decide what to depend is the same thing - and some of the tools mentioned there are command line. good luck.

Comment: Sounds nice, but I'm really having difficulties finding the right tool. Ah well, guess I'll just have to dig through some more.

Comment: even [include-what-you-use](https://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/) that was linked on the existing question?